# Enum conversion of UIInterfaceOrientation to AVCaptureVideoOrientation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm playing around with using AVFoundation in Swift

Normally when I set up a video camera capture session I do something like the following in objective-c

```
[[cameraView.previewLayer connection] setVideoOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)[self interfaceOrientation]]
```

In swift it seems like I have to do something like this (because of optional type)

```
if let connection = cameraView.previewLayer?.connection {
  connection.videoOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation as AVCaptureVideoOrientation
}
```

however this complains with

```
‘AVCaptureVideoOrientation’ is not a subtype of ‘UIInterfaceOrientation’
```

After reading about the down-casting methodology this makes a lot of sense, but I'm struggling to find how to actually get this working.

Do I need to write a helper method that basically does a switch statement through all the available values of UIInterfaceOrientation to get this working?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As I noted in my comments, since AVCaptureVideoOrientation and UIInterfaceOrientation don't match up their cases, you can use something like:

```
extension AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
    var uiInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .LandscapeLeft:        return .LandscapeLeft
            case .LandscapeRight:       return .LandscapeRight
            case .Portrait:             return .Portrait
            case .PortraitUpsideDown:   return .PortraitUpsideDown
            }
        }
    }

    init(ui:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        switch ui {
        case .LandscapeRight:       self = .LandscapeRight
        case .LandscapeLeft:        self = .LandscapeLeft
        case .Portrait:             self = .Portrait
        case .PortraitUpsideDown:   self = .PortraitUpsideDown
        default:                    self = .Portrait
        }
    }
}
```

then use it as:

```
if let connection = cameraView.previewLayer?.connection {
    connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(ui:self.interfaceOrientation)
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much for posting this! Was just about to write the same code.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks, David. I updated to Swift 3 and added UIDeviceOrientation:

```
extension AVCaptureVideoOrientation {
    var uiInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .landscapeLeft:        return .landscapeLeft
            case .landscapeRight:       return .landscapeRight
            case .portrait:             return .portrait
            case .portraitUpsideDown:   return .portraitUpsideDown
            }
        }
    }

    init(ui:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        switch ui {
        case .landscapeRight:       self = .landscapeRight
        case .landscapeLeft:        self = .landscapeLeft
        case .portrait:             self = .portrait
        case .portraitUpsideDown:   self = .portraitUpsideDown
        default:                    self = .portrait
        }
    }

    init?(orientation:UIDeviceOrientation) {
        switch orientation {
        case .landscapeRight:       self = .landscapeLeft
        case .landscapeLeft:        self = .landscapeRight
        case .portrait:             self = .portrait
        case .portraitUpsideDown:   self = .portraitUpsideDown
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Then I use it with AVCapturePhotoOutput like this:

```
if let connection = imageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo),
    connection.isVideoOrientationSupported,
    let orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(orientation: UIDevice.current.orientation) {
    connection.videoOrientation = orientation
}
```

It may not be perfect for every scenario but since my interface doesn't change with orientation I skip listening for orientation changes.

It's probably better in general to change your UI so users have an idea of what orientation they're using.

Answer (score 6):

## swift 3

```
extension UIDeviceOrientation {
    var videoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation? {
        // Unlike UIInterfaceOrientation, the UIDeviceOrientation has reversed landscape left/right. Doh!
        switch self {
        case .portraitUpsideDown: return .portraitUpsideDown
        case .landscapeRight: return .landscapeLeft
        case .landscapeLeft: return .landscapeRight
        case .portrait: return .portrait
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}

extension UIInterfaceOrientation {
    var videoOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation? {
        switch self {
        case .portraitUpsideDown: return .portraitUpsideDown
        case .landscapeRight: return .landscapeRight
        case .landscapeLeft: return .landscapeLeft
        case .portrait: return .portrait
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a mistake in this code. In the first case block of converting `UIDeviceOrientation`  to `AVCaptureVideoOrientation`, the case of `landscapeRight` does not return `landscapeLeft`

Comment: @thuanle Yeah `UIDeviceOrientation` landscape left/right is reversed. I have added a comment to the code, so it doesn't look like a simple mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the comment

Comment: Swift is awesome, but seems to add areas of complexity where none should exist. This is one such case. So smooth in so many ways, and then stuff like this comes along. But thank you, this code helps!

Answer (score -1):

Posted this about 10 minutes too soon.

Figured out, if you stumble across this, doing something like

```
connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.fromRaw(self.interfaceOrientation.toRaw())!
```

seems to work.

Comment: Note that this actually is incorrect because the landscape left and landscape right values are flipped between `AVCaptureVideoOrientation` and `UIInterfaceOrientation`

Comment: Voted as incorrect because landscape orientation values doesn't match in the two enums.

Comment: the code is not working properly because raw values are not meet at the same point.